# Image Upload without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to upload an image using iframe without page refresh.The code works fine in FF & Chrome but in IE it gives the error "Access Denied".

Below is the html code to upload the profile picture with target to iframe.

```
<form action="/image-upload" id="frmuploadPicture" name="frmuploadPicture" target="upload_iframe" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:user.openUploadDialog('profileImage');">Edit Photo</a>
                    <input type="file" id="profileImage" name="profileImage" style="-ms-filter:'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)'; filter: alpha(opacity=0);opacity: 0;" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" onchange="javascript:user.uploadProfileImage(this);"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="txtUserId" value="879987"/>
             </form>
            <iframe name="upload_iframe" src="" style="width: 400px; height: 100px; display: none;"></iframe>
```

I have a edit photo link only displayed to the user and on the click of this edit link i trigger click event of file element and on the change of file element i submit the form.

i am submitting the form using document.frmuploadPicture.submit(); on change of file element.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) to upload your image through ajax:

[Demo](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html)